# Count amount of differences and return column name with count

Tags: vba, excel

i am finding the differences between 2 worksheets, the code is as follows:

```
For Each mycell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtSheet2).UsedRange 
If Not mycell.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtSheet1).Cells(mycell.Row, mycell.Column).Value Then
    mycell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
    difference = difference + 1
End If

If mycell.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtSheet1).Cells(mycell.Row, mycell.Column).Value Then
   matches = matches + 1
End If
```

When the values in the cells do not match it highlights that cell yellow and increments the count so I know the total amount of differences.

I have the headers Department, Name, Sales, Date Start, Date end.  How can I return the amount of differences for the columns?

e.g.

```
Differences 
department : 3 
sales : 0
Date Start : 1
Date end : 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have `difference` as an `Array`, and increment the component corresponding to the current `Column`.
You can do something similar with `matches` if you want. Plus, you can abbreviate your two `If`s.

```
Dim difference(1 To 5) As Long
Dim matches(1 To 5) As Long
For Each mycell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtSheet2).UsedRange
Dim col as Long
col = mycell.Column
If Not mycell.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtSheet1).Cells(mycell.Row, mycell.Column).Value Then
    mycell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
    difference(col) = difference(col) + 1
Else
    matches(col) = matches(col) + 1
End If
```

You may check [Chip Pearson's guide](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbaarrays.htm).

Comment: thanks! i am running into issues with this, since I am new to VB, i keep getting the error Object variable or with block variable not set on the line "col = mycell.Column"

Comment: @Tony - I skipped the first line, with the understanding that you would keep it. Now I added it. Please check updated code. If needed, carry out a little debugging.

Comment: I've spent some time trying to debug and learning about arrays but unfortunately can't seem to get it to work, any more advice?

Comment: thanks! however when i used the debug.print matches(col) this just gives me the amount of matches (12) and the same for the differences rather than listing me the matches and errors in each column as shown above in my question

Comment: @Tony - Of course, `difference` stores `Long` (integer) values. If you want to print the headers, you have to do it explcitly, e.g., `debug.print "Department: " & matches(1)`.